# ¿Cómo hacer una animación para el movimiento horizontal de slider con CSS y react?

Tags: css, reactjs, slider, animacion-css

Estoy haciendo un slider con css y react

Tengo dos estados para mostrar una clase, mover el contenido hacia la izquierda o hacia la derecha según el botón que se presione

cuando doy a siguiente avanza la posición que quiero pero en el segundo clic vuelve a la posición original en lugar de avanzar

¿Cómo podría seguir avanzando?

Además de esto cuando coloco con la segunda clase pero con el movimiento contrario parece que se anulan y solo funciona una.

¿Cómo podría evitar que esto sucediera?
dejo parte del codigo

```
const [next, setNext] = useState(true);
 const [prev, setPrev] = useState(false)
 const nextSlide = () => setNext(!next)
 const previouSide = () => setPrev(!prev)
 <>
      <BlogHearder>
        <div className='featues-header'>
          <h2 className='features-title'>Visit Our Blog</h2>
          <div className='feature-arrows'>
            <button className='feature-icon icon-left' onClick={previouSide}>
              <FiChevronLeft className='icon' />
            </button>
            <button className='feature-icon icon-right' onClick={nextSlide}>
              <FiChevronRight className='icon' />
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </BlogHearder>
      <BlogCardWrapper ref={ref} >
        <div className={next ? 'blog-slider next' : 'blog-slider', prev? 'blog-slider' : 'blog-slider prev'  }>
          {state.map(blog => (
            <BlogCard key={blog.id} blog={blog} />
          ))}
        </div>
      </BlogCardWrapper>
     
    </>
```

Estoy usando styled components

```
BlogCardWrapper = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  overflow: hidden;
  .next{ 
    transform:translateX(-19%)
  }
  .prev{
    transform: translateX(19%);
  }
  .blog-slider {
    width: 250%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    transition: all 0.5s;
  }
`
```

para el movimiento horizontal hacia la derecha la clase .next y hacia la izquierda .prev

19% es el tamaño de mis tarjetas deslizantes

Gracias de antemano a quien pueda ayudarme.

Answer (score 0):

Sucede que cuando tu quieres presionar el boton next por segunda vez, cambiara el estado next a false! entonces retrocedera.

El segundo error sucede por que ahora luego de apretar en los dos botones tienes dos clases presentes, que se contradicen .
mi solucion es poner un ref en el div que se movera. y cambiar los estilos
desde una funcion en las flechas o de donde quieras que el usuario presione:

Deberias encontrar la forma de tener el index de tu foto para saber cuantas veces tienes que mover 19% por ejemplo

```
   const funcion = (event) =>{

           const index_de_foto = event.target.id

           const translatePercentage = index_de_foto * 19

           ref.current.style.transform=
                             `translateX({translatePercentage}%)`}
```